# React-Admin: How to edit another Component value after 1 has changed (eg, subtotal+discount=total)?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Eg, I have a CreateInvoice returning something like this:

```js
<[...] src='subtotal' />
<[...] src='discount' />
<[...] src='total' disabled />
```

Whenever subtotal or discount are changed, in perhaps `onChange`, how can I refer to the disabled `total` Component to sum the vals from `subtotal + discount`?

(If the answer has to do with `states`, a code example would be great -- RA seems to handle states differently and I'm already new to React, so I've been very confused by the lack of `state` documentation in RA docs)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having the subtotal and discount maintained in a state . Then you can pass an additional prop to the the total component .

```
< ... src="total" total={subtotal + discount} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `<FormDataConsumer />` https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs

Alternatively, you can leverage react-final-form directly with the `useForm` prop.

```
import {useForm} from 'react-final-form';
const SubtotalInput = props => {
  const form = useForm();
  return (
    <TextInput src='subtotal' onChange={(event) => {
      const newSubtotal = parseFloat(event.target.value);
      form.change('total', newSubtotal + form.getState().values.discount);
    }} />
  )
}
```